# Koa2 Same Route Different Params

Tags: koa, koa2

I have two endpoints:

**GET all users by ID**

```
http.get(API_URL + "users/" + id)
```

**GET all users by username**

```
http.get(API_URL + "users/" + username)
```

Can I send different parameters on a same route:

```
router.get("/users/:id",  async ctx => {
    //ctx.request.param is id 
    //do something

});


router.get("/users/:username",  async ctx => {
    //ctx.request.param is username 
    //do something
});
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

In your example, you are providing URL parameters, not (named) query parameters, so it is just a part of the URL, so this is anyway "just a string".

This means, that koa router would then be aware of data types (e.g. `integer` for `:id` and `string` for `:name`). This is - as far as I know - not the case.

When you have

```
"/users/:id"
```

or

```
"/users/:username"
```

you just give this part of the URL string a name - nothing more. (ctx.params.id **OR** ctx.params.username)

So you need to implement a logic, where you determine if the parameter is an integer (and handle is as an ID) or not (in which case you handle it as a username).

This could look like that:

```
router.get("/users/:id",  async ctx => {
    //ctx.request.id
    if (!isNaN(ctx.request.id)) // it IS a number {
        //do something with user ID
    } else {
        //do something with username
    }
});
```

hope that makes sense ... otherwise, you really have to create two routes with a distingiashable signature

Answer (score 0):

short answer is no.

I think the good solution maybe, your route setup like this

```
GET /users?<your query here>
```

then your can query your users with `<your query>.id` or query>.username